# Show without a calculator : $e^{-\gamma}<\omega$

Tags: inequality, constants

Hi I think this question is new :

Problem :

Show that :

$$e^{-\gamma}<\omega$$

Where we have the Euler's number and constant and omega constant wich is the value taking at $x=1$ of the Lambert's function .

I recall two interesting fact on The Lambert function :

$$W_{0}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}}x^{n}$$

And the Euler-Mascheroni constant can be determined via the Harmonic numbers .

Question :

Can we hope to find a proof by hand without calculator as if Euler meet Lambert at the 18 century ?

Thanks !

Comment: The problem is equivalent to $$
e^{ - \gamma } e^{e^{ - \gamma } }  < 1 \Leftrightarrow e^{e^{ - \gamma } }  < e^\gamma   \Leftrightarrow e^{ - \gamma }  < \gamma \Leftrightarrow 1 < \gamma e^{  \gamma }  \Leftrightarrow \omega < \gamma.
$$

Comment: @Gary, Nice observation! I guess we can simplify your derivation a bit:$$e^{-\gamma}<\omega\quad\iff\quad e^{\omega-\gamma}<\omega e^{\omega}=1\quad\iff\quad \omega-\gamma<0\quad\iff\quad\omega<\gamma.$$

Comment: I am sorry but Pascal presented the *Pascaline* in 1645. Euler & Lambert worked together in 1783. So, they had a computing device.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici So thanks to Pascal to invented the irrational Pascaline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Omega constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant)
$\Omega = W_0(1)$ is the unique solution for real $x$ of $xe^x = 1,$
therefore it is strictly less than the unique positive solution $a$
of the equation $p(a) = 1,$ where $p(x) = x + x^2 + x^3/2 + x^4/6$
(a strictly increasing function of $x$ for $x \geqslant 0$). We will
show that $p(4/7) > 1,$ whence $a < 4/7,$ whence:
$$
\Omega < 4/7.
$$
Proof:
$$
p\left(\frac47\right) =
\frac47 + \frac{16}{49} + \frac{32}{343}\cdot\frac{25}{21} =
\frac{44}{49} + \frac{800}{7203} =
\frac{44}{49} + \frac19\left(1 - \frac3{7203}\right) >
\frac{44}{49} + \frac19\left(1 - \frac4{49}\right) = 1.
$$

Because $\Omega = e^{-\Omega},$ the required inequality is
equivalent to $e^{-\gamma} < e^{-\Omega},$ whence (as has been
pointed out in the comments) it is equivalent to $\Omega < \gamma.$
It is therefore enough to prove that:
$$
\gamma > 4/7.
$$

The Wikipedia page for
[Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.orgwiki/Euler%27s_constant),
referring to Duane W. DeTemple, "A Quicker Convergence to Euler's
Constant", *The American Mathematical Monthly* **100**
(5), pp. 468–470, states that for each positive integer $n,$
\begin{equation}
\label{4337532:eq:1}\tag{1}
\frac1{24(n+1)^2} <
\gamma_n\left(\frac12\right) - \gamma < \frac1{24n^2},
\end{equation}
where for all $\alpha > -n,$
$$
\gamma_n(\alpha) =
1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \cdots + \frac1n - \log_e(n + \alpha).
$$
We only need take $n = 2$ in \eqref{4337532:eq:1}, obtaining:
$$
\gamma > \frac{143}{96} - \log_e\left(\frac52\right).
$$
Temporarily taking for granted this inequality (whose hairy proof is exiled to a separate section below):
\begin{equation}
\label{4337532:eq:2}\tag{2}
\log_e\left(\frac52\right) < \frac{11}{12},
\end{equation}
we conclude
$$
\gamma > \frac{143}{96} - \frac{11}{12} = \frac{55}{96} > \frac47,
$$
whence $\gamma > \Omega$ (as explained above). $\square$

---

**Proof** of \eqref{4337532:eq:2}:

\begin{gather*}
\log_e\left(\frac52\right) = \log_e\left(\frac{10}4\right) =
\log_e\frac{1 + 3/7}{1-3/7} \\
= 2\left(\frac37 + \frac{3^3}{3\cdot7^3} + \frac{3^5}{5\cdot7^5} +
\frac{3^7}{7\cdot7^7} + \frac{3^9}{9\cdot7^9} +
\frac{3^{11}}{11\cdot7^{11}} + \cdots\right) \\
< 2\left(\frac37 + \frac{3^3}{3\cdot7^3} + \frac{3^5}{5\cdot7^5} +
\frac{3^7}{7\cdot7^7}\left(
1 + \frac{3^2}{7^2} + \frac{3^4}{7^4} + \cdots\right)\right) \\
= 2\left(\frac37 + \frac{3^3}{3\cdot7^3} + \frac{3^5}{5\cdot7^5} +
\frac{3^7}{7\cdot7^7}\cdot\frac{49}{40}\right)
= 2\left(\frac37 + \frac{3^3}{3\cdot7^3} + \frac{3^5}{5\cdot7^5} +
\frac{3^7}{5\cdot7^6\cdot8}\right) \\
= 2\left(\frac37 + \frac{3^3}{3\cdot7^3} +
\frac{3^5}{5\cdot7^5}\left(1 + \frac9{56}\right)\right)
= 2\left(\frac37 + \frac{3^3}{3\cdot7^3} +
\frac{3^5}{5\cdot7^5}\cdot\frac{65}{56}\right) \\
= \frac67\left(1 + \frac3{49} +
\frac{3^4}{5\cdot7^4}\cdot\frac{65}{56}\right)
= \frac67\left(1 + \frac3{49} + \frac{3^4\cdot13}{7^5\cdot8}\right).
\end{gather*}
So we have to prove
\begin{gather*}
1 + \frac3{49} + \frac{3^4\cdot13}{7^5\cdot8} < \frac{77}{72},
\text{ i.e., }\
\frac3{49} + \frac{3^4\cdot13}{7^5\cdot8} < \frac5{72},
\text{ i.e., }\ \frac{216}{49} + \frac{3^6\cdot13}{7^5} < 5,\\
\text{ i.e., }\ \frac{20}{49} + \frac{3^6\cdot13}{7^5} < 1,
\text{ i.e., }\ \frac{3^6\cdot13}{7^5} < \frac{29}{7^2},
\text{ i.e., }\ 729\cdot13 < 343\cdot29,
\end{gather*}
i.e., $9477 < 9947$ - which is true. $\square$